# GRAILS: passing an object to every view?

Tags: grails

assuming i have a filter (which is being invoked before every action), how can I pass an object, which is fetched from the database in it to every view? I do not want to refactor 
all my methods.

To vizualize:

I have a filter that sets an object, for example:

```
def god = God.find(1)
```

and I have 100 controllers, for each controllers 100 methods, which is 100 * 100 views. 
Usually in the action you write something like :

```
def index = {
 def something = Something.find(1)
 [something: something]
}
```

the question is how can I pass `God` object as well, without having to modify the return array to

```
[something: something, god: god]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want an `after` interceptor type to your filter for that. `after` takes `model` as an argument to the closure, and you can add god to that model.

```
myFilter(controller:'*', action:'*') {
    after = { model ->
        def god = God.find(1)
        model.god = god
    }
}
```

[Here's](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filterTypes) the relevant docs section.

Answer (score 1):

other place where you can do the same thing is afterInterceptor. [Here](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Controllers/afterInterceptor.html) is the documentation for the same. afterInterceptor is best suited when you have some business logic for extracting the object and don't want to copy the same logic to filters.

Comment: does not apply i guess, you set interceptors in controller, right?